# rock Paper Scissors HMAC(SHA-3 or SHA-2) encryption

Tags: python, hmac, sha2, sha-3

I have a game( rock Paper Scissors).
How to encrypt the answer of the computer using HMAC (SHA-2 or SHA-3) and at the end of the game compare with the answer of the user?

```py
import random
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

options = {"r": "rock", "p": "paper", "s": "scissors"}

while True:
    user = input('Choose r for rock, p for paper, s for scissors or q to quit: ')
    user = user.lower()

    if user == 'q':
        break
    if user not in options.keys():
        continue

    choice = random.choice(list(options.keys()))
    print('Computer picked:', options[choice])

    if choice == user:
        print('You tie against the computer\n')
    elif (user, choice) in (("r", "s"), ("p", "r"), ("s", "p")):
        print('You win against the computer\n')
    else:
        print('You lose against the computer\n')
```

Comment: Why do you need to encrypt it?

Comment: And if you really can come up with a reason, the hashing is trivial, but a significant challenge is how to encode (essentially, garble) the input so that an eavesdropper cannot simply observe the game for a few rounds and figure out which hash corresponds to which outcome.

Comment: Check if the computer is cheating.And this is my assignment from the teacher

Comment: What do you mean by "computer is cheating", and how does encryption help? Clarify the assignment with the teacher. In any case, usage of HMAC in Python is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/hmac.html).

Comment: As I understand it, hmac is needed to encrypt the response of the computer.
In the code, you need to generate a computer response from the arguments passed (1 a z ...), encrypt it with hmac, and then display
After the user has entered his answer, we decrypt the answer, compare it with the user's answer, determine who will win

Comment: HMAC is not encryption algorithm, it's an authenticated hash (signature). You cannot decrypt it, you can only verify the message consistency.

Comment: And how can you create a hash and check the sequence of computer response messages?